# How to parse the image href in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing a web page using Nokogiri, and would like to parse out an image URL. This is my setup:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://themeforest.net/search?sort=sales'))
```

I can see the following code block if I inspect the page on chrome:

```
<div class="_2_3rp " style="padding-top:50.847457627118644%">            
  <div style=""> 
    <img class="_1xvs1" src="https://themeforest.img.customer.envatousercontent.com/files/274559780/screenshots/00-Preview.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=crop&amp;crop=top&amp;w=590&amp;h=300&amp;s=37354d884fd0f3b574238e013b4ea423"                                         
      title="Avada | Responsive Multi-Purpose Theme"                    
      alt="Avada | Responsive Multi-Purpose Theme" style="left: 0%;">            
  </div>                                                                     
</div>
```

However, when I run:

```
puts doc.search("//div[@class = '_2_3rp ']")
```

I get the following:

```
  <div class="_2_3rp " style="padding-top:50.847457627118644%"><div style="height:100%" class="lazyload-placeholder"></div></div>
  <div class="_2_3rp " style="padding-top:50.847457627118644%"><div style="height:100%" class="lazyload-placeholder"></div></div>
  .....
  => nil
```

Why am I not getting the `img` class, and instead getting `lazyload-placeholder`? Is there any way I can get over this, and escape the image placeholder?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When asking remove every non-essential piece of information from your code and data. I can't duplicate the problem so I  think it's somewhere in something you're not showing us. And, the "following" output couldn't be from the input HTML because the second `div` `style` is different.

Comment: @theTinMan I have updated my question with the exact code. This is the only way I could form a reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the minimal code I came up with that's necessary to test your assertion:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="12345">
    <div>
        <img class="67890" src="https://foo.bar">
    </div>
</div>
EOT

doc.search('//div[@class=12345]').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<div class=\"12345\">\n" +
#     "    <div>\n" +
#     "        <img class=\"67890\" src=\"https://foo.bar\">\n" +
#     "    </div>\n" +
#     "</div>"]
#     "</div>"]
```

It looks like the `img` tag is there.

You're using `Nokogiri::XML` to parse. Don't, because strict parsing occurs and with HTML, which is anything but strict, problems can occur if the HTML is malformed.

Comment: Parsing with `Nokogiri::HTML` returned the same result